# ¿Como brindar permisos USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, permisos

Tengo una aplicación que debe de bloquear el dispositivo pasado determinado tiempo, encontré que se puede realizar con la instrucción `lockNow()`, pero al ponerlo y ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7
>                     Process: com.example.software.appvideos, PID: 11915
>                     java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10151 for policy #3
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1704)
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1654)
>                         at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.lockNow(IDevicePolicyManager.java:5262)
>                         at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.lockNow(DevicePolicyManager.java:2533)
>                         at com.example.software.appvideos.MainActivity$11.run(MainActivity.java:256)

Por lo poco que entendí al buscar se necesitan permisos para poder ejecutar la instrucción si me pudieran ayudar con este pequeño problema les estaría muy agradecido. Anexo mi manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.software.appvideos">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Fullscreen"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Y el código donde declaro el lockNow().

```
DevicePolicyManager  pm = (DevicePolicyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

public void apagar(){
    Thread t = new Thread(){

        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    pm.lockNow();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: que API estas usando?

Comment: Si estas usando android Marshmallow o mayor en tu dispositivo no olvides que tienes que solicitar los permisos en tiempo de ejecución o activar los permisos desde la configuración de la aplicación.

Comment: Utilizo api 28 @IgmerRodriguez

Comment: @Serna me puedes decir como pedir permisos desde la configuración de la aplicación, lamento las molestias pero soy nuevo en el mundo de Android

Comment: @Alfredo No te preocupes para eso estamos, Seria ir Configuraciones -> Aplicaciones -> "Tu app" -> Permisos y ya en ese apartado los habilitas.

Comment: @Serna ya lo intente pero no me aparece ningún tipo de permiso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad  `pm.lockNow()` no será permitido sin antes habitar  esta política, provoca un error del tipo `SecurityException` ya que la aplicación que llama no posee un administrador activo que use `DeviceAdminInfo.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK` para realizar esto te agrego un tutorial.

## Como bloquear pantalla en Android ( Screen lock )

Crea una clase que extienda de `DeviceAdminReceiver`:

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;

public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

}
```

En tu archivos `AndroidManifest.xml` registra la clase receiver:

```
<application>
  ...
  ...

        <receiver
            android:name=".AdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

 </application>
```

Dentro de `/res` crea el directorio `/xml` y dentro crea el archivo `device_admin.xml` que será donde definirás la política que permitirá cerrar el dispositivo:

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock/>
    </uses-policies>

</device-admin>
```

Este sería el ejemplo de tu Activity:

```
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    protected static final int REQUEST_ENABLE = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Throws
        //SecurityException if the calling application does not own an active administrator that uses DeviceAdminInfo.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK

        //https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminInfo#USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK

        //A type of policy that this device admin can use: able to force the device to lock
        //Un tipo de política que el administrador de este dispositivo puede usar: capaz de forzar el bloqueo del dispositivo

        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
        DevicePolicyManager mgr = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

        if (mgr.isAdminActive(cn)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "User is an admin!");
            mgr.lockNow();
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "User is NOT an admin!");
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, cn);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);

        }


    }
}
```

Si no esta activado el administrador del dispositivo, el `intent` sera el encargado de abrir la pantalla de configuración, para que el usuario determine como y cuando se realice el bloqueo de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se puede descargar un ejemplo completo.

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Screen-Lock

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me funciono de maravilla, eres grande me acabas de salvar el pellejo.

Comment: Excelente @Alfredo agregué más información a mi respuesta y un ejemplo, saludos!